# Orientation change makes things null

Tags: android, fragment

Alright, so I'm having a bit of a problem and obviously by the title I'm not exactly sure how to phrase it ("makes things null"? really?)

Anyway, I have a `Fragment` inside of a `FragmentActivity` that, when the `Fragment` is created, immediately throws a dialog on the screen and begins an `AsyncTask` (which grabs info off a server). The problem I'm coming across is when I change the orientation while the AsyncTask is occurring.

At first I kept getting a "your activity has leaked a window" or something like that because of the dialog that was showing (I easily just canceled the dialog in `onPause`), however, now I'm seeing that the orientation change is calling `getActivity()` from inside the `Fragment` returns null as well as a `SharedPreference` that holds the IP address becomes null (and, since it can't find value of the `SharedPreference`, it goes to the default value which is an empty string.

So, how can I work with this orientation change?

Comment: can't really tell if it's a duplicate but the answer Martin Cazares gave is different than the one in the link and it works.

Comment: Is your asynctask internal to class? or is it static?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want your fragment to be recreated and totally affected by the Configuration Changed mechanism of the OS why dont you just set your Fragment as:

```
fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
```

This will prevent your fragment from being re-created when a configuration change is going on the parent activity as per Google's doc:

> Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity
>   re-creation (such as from a configuration change). This can only be
>   used with fragments not in the back stack. If set, the fragment
>   lifecycle will be slightly different when an activity is recreated

Hope this Helps!

Regards!

Comment: Yep, testing it now and it's working so far.

Comment: Good, if the answer was helpful would be nice if you mark it as correct, so people take the time answer your questions later on.

Comment: Patience is a virtue. "You can accept an answer in 2 minutes"